# Slide Element Up Into Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I was wondering how I could slide up a banner at the bottom of my page that is hidden.

For instance:

- Page loads
- 3 seconds later, the banner slides up from bottom of page

I want to be able to do this without any scrollbars appearing (no change in page height) and without revealing the banner prior to it sliding up.

I looked at `slideUp()` and `slideToggle()`, but I couldn't find a way to make it work to my liking :-/

Here's what I originally tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('.serverad').delay(3000).slideToggle('slow', function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
    });
```

And the CSS was `visiblity: hidden;`

Comment: It is going to be a lot of work for a little effect. `.slideUp()` is for an in place effect. Sliding it from the bottom of the page would require a fair bit of work, and would probably be very annoying for users.

Comment: I think you should be more specific how the effect should work. For example, what do you mean by “bottom of page”? The bottom of the whole document or the bottom edge of the browser’s view port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a position:fixed on the banner ad, and animate the bottom attribute to 0
have the initial bottom attribute be the a negative of its height.

```
<style>
    .serverad
    {
         height:60px;
         position:fixed;
         left:0px;
         bottom:-60px;
    }
</style>    

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
              $('.serverad').delay(3000).animate({bottom:"0px"},600);
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. techfoobar's was also good, but he didn't use jQuery's delay, which requires more work than needed.

Answer (score 1):

Animate the height property instead of top:

In you CSS:

```
.serverad {
    ...
    height: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    visiblity: visible;
    overflow: hidden;
    ...
}
```

And in your JS, change the animation code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.serverad').delay(3000).animate({height: '30px'}, 'slow', function() {
       // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Comment: Edited my answer. There was a comma missing before `'slow'` !

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want something along these lines:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="serveraddcontainer">
        <div class="serveradd"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;    
}

.serveraddcontainer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -80px;
}

.serveradd{
    width: 400px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: red; 
    margin: auto;
}
```

Javascript:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.serveraddcontainer').animate({'bottom': '0'});
}, 3000);
```

[***Example JSFiddle Here***](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/XFyLq/)

Comment: The position:absolute would make it scroll with the page, more then likely wants it to stay at the bottom at all times. fixed would be better

Comment: @PatrickEvans I assumed his page has no scrolling since he said he doesn't want a scrollbar to appear, but you are right if his page does have scrolling fixed would be better. Although I don't think position: fixed works in IE6

Comment: yea i took that to mean he didnt want scrollbars appearing/disappearing from the animation, which your body css takes care of, but would then hide content, as not everyones viewport size will be bigger then the content.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
var stepDurations = 3000;
var reveal = window.setTimeout(
    function(){
        $('#banner').animate(
            {
                'height' : '30px'
            }, stepDurations,
            function(){
                $(this).animate(
                    {
                        'bottom' : $(window).height() - $(this).height()
                    }, stepDurations);
            });
    },stepDurations);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qv48v/).

---

Turned the above into a function:

```
function slideReveal(target, height, stepDuration, revealName){
    if (!target) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var height = height || '30px',
            stepDuration = stepDuration || 2000,
            revealName = revealName || 'reveal';

        revealName = window.setTimeout(
            function(){
                $(target).animate(
                    {
                        'height' : height
                    }, stepDuration,
                    function(){
                        $(this).animate(
                            {
                                'bottom' : $(window).height() - $(this).height()
                            }, stepDuration);
                    });
            },stepDuration);
    }
};

// call with:

slideReveal($('#banner'), '3em', 100, 'revelation');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/qv48v/2/).